# HTTP 500 error after updating to appengine 1.7.7

Tags: google-app-engine

We are trying to update our (Java + Maven) project to appengine 1.7.7 but when we run the devserver now requests, even for small static content, take ~10 seconds and end with an HTTP 500 error with the message "Got request to server -1.default but the instance is busy".  This message seems to originate in BackendServersFilter.java (one of the AppEngine classes) but is a little odd since we're not making a request for a backend at that point.  Is anyone else seeing this behavior with their app updating to appengine 1.7.7?  If so, has anyone found a solution?

BTW, the ONLY thing I change in my project to produce this behavior is the appengine version from 1.7.6 to 1.7.7 in my Maven POM file.

Comment: FWIW I'm still seeing this error in 1.8.0 of appengine.  I can't even access "_ah/admin" without getting this error.  The ONLY think I'm changing in my project is updating from 1.7.6 of appengine to 1.7.7 or, now, 1.8.0.

Comment: Okay, found the issue (sort of).  Apparently 1.7.7 and beyond don't care for our naming a backend "default".  Presumably this is used internally somewhere and the result is that the request is routed strangely and ends up not being handled in the right place or something along those lines.  Upon further inspection of the Backends docs it appears "default" is reserved:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends#Backends_Definitions

I don't know whether the pre-1.7.7 docs warned of this.  None the less a more informative error would be splendid.